# WPF: Customized regional settings

Tags: wpf, string, localization

I just found out today that WPF will ignore CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and always use en-US. I have also found a wonderful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764615/wpf-stringformat-0c-showing-as-dollars). Everything worked fine until one of the users customized the regional settings to change the currency symbol (here in the Philippines you could write Php and P and most people prefer P, the default setting is Php). The application doesn't seem to pick this up. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Someone wrote a replacement for the default Bindings which sets the ConverterCulture as you would expect it: http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/localized-value-formatting-in-wpf/

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but the geek in me finds the statement "Php is the default in the Philippines" funny :)

Comment: Same problem exactly! Anyone has answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a week's research of two people, I think there is currently no way of doing this using the Globalization classes.

CurrentUICulture and other related classes contain the default formats/settings for the selected Language but not the customized settings.

One way to do this is by reading the values straight from the registry key, HKCU\Control Panel\International.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to check for the current country setup for my C# WPF application. 
I used CurrentCulture and not CurrentUICulture (which picked up EN-US for me too).

Also, I'm not sure this will help- but I found out I was testing this functionality in the wrong place.

To change the country of your app for testing go to:
“Control Panel->Clock, Language, and Region” select the “Region and Language” button, a window will pop up, go to the format tab, change the country in the format listbox.

Once I did that CurrentCulture worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to make WPF use *customized* regional settings, but you need to force all bindings to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149978/currentuiculture-ignores-region-and-language-settings/14163432) for examples.

Comment: Not *quite* true. ShortTimePattern ignores the regional settings. Everything else works as you suggest.