# WPF, changing NumberFormatInfo of current culture doesn't work

Tags: wpf, globalization

In App.xaml.cs I have:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                       .CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;

NumberFormatInfo nfi = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                       .CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
```

Now in a different window, which will be opened from the MainWindow, I wrote the following:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat=c}"
```

But the result is something like $1,200.00, not what I expected: USD1,200. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

There might be smarter ways, but this should work consistently...

```
// xmlns:sysglb="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
<TextBox Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture={x:Static sysglb:CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture}}" />
```

And move this at app startup or ctor...

Then do the `OverrideMetadata` and before `base.OnStartup` - e.g...

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

    NumberFormatInfo nfi = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                            .CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;

    nfi = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                            .CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat;
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
    nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;

    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

    base.OnStartup(e);

}
```

See also:

[WPF StringFormat={0:C} showing as dollars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764615/wpf-stringformat-0c-showing-as-dollars/12115452#12115452)

Comment: Your code could work, but what I'm trying to achieve is dynamically change NumberFormat when a culture-specific database is opened. Your code requires to restart the app again.

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormatting is an operation that uses your CurrentCulture (by default unless you explicitly provide a Culture or NumberFormatter to the method) NOT CurrentUICulture. CurrentUICulture is used for resource (localization) lookup.

The NumberFormatInfo you get from the CurrentCulture should be read only [(see Remarks of NumberFormatInfo documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) and should throw an InvalidOperationException when you attempt to set any of the properties [(see Remarks of NumberFormatinfo.IsReadOnly)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.isreadonly.aspx/html). (Are you swallowing this exception?) If you create a writable CultureInfo and change its properties, you can then set that as your current culture.

You need to do something like:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
NumberFormatInfo nfi= ci.NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "USD";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
// set the default culture for all threads that haven't been explicitly set (.Net 4.5)
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = ci;
// or the following if you aren't using .Net 4.5
// Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: I checked; nfi.IsReadOnly equals to false. The code works; CurrencyDecimalDigits becomes from 2 to 0. I also copy/pasted your code, but nothing changed.