# Best way to set CurrentCulture so it applies to all WPF components

Tags: wpf, binding, localization

I've just learnt to my surprise that [WPF doesn't use the CurrentCulture for bindings, instead defaulting to en-US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display).

In a pure WPF application, this can be fixed in one place by [setting the language globally once in the App class](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/796725.aspx).

However I have a WinForms application that is being progressively migrated to WPF, and contains several WPF UserControls.  What's the best/simplest way to ensure the CurrentCulture is used for all UserControls?  Do I really have to make all my UserControls inherit from a base class that does this, or is there some way to set it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a slightly different approach and derive once from `ElementHost` and manipulate your WPF `UserControl` instances as they are instantiated.  For example, you can create a `LocalizingElementHost` with a `ChildChanged` event handler that does to the child what you would have done in a base class.

Comment: Changed my accepted answer to this one.  Deriving from ElementHost is looking more and more attractive - the latest good reason being to implement the workaround in this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955753

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the same approach with `LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata`, just put it at the beginning of your program (`Main` method).

Comment: +1 - both this and Rick Sladkey's answers are equally valid, I'm accepting this one as it's what I ended up implementing.