# decimal removed after validation @ WPF Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I create a Textbox in Code behinde and bind it to a double Property.

```
                TextBox t = new TextBox();
                t.Width = 80;
                t.DataContext = s;         
                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(t, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

When I enter a value like 45,45 (comma) it is parsed to 4545.

If I enter 45.45 (point) it is parsed correctly with 45,45.

I use German language Settings and my decimal separator is `,`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting binding.[ConverterCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterculture.aspx) to your target culture.

For example

```
 binding.ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: I'm glad it works, but Dummy01's answer may be better.  Give it a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831455/use-real-cultureinfo-currentculture-in-wpf-binding-not-cultureinfo-from-ietfl

Answer (score 2):

A clear, not culture specific solution is to add this to your App.xaml.cs and normally WPF will always use the correct culture - regional settings:

```
    static App()
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
```

Comment: Strange... if you do a breakpoint there what value the XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag) returns?

Comment: actually it isn't called at all

Comment: This is impossible because this is the static constructor of your application. It should be called once during the startup.

Comment: ...Unless you changed the name of you startup class from App to something else

Comment: That works most of the time. However, if the user has changed the standards for that language, then it won't work. Thus, you need to use a "culture-aware" binding, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831455/use-real-cultureinfo-currentculture-in-wpf-binding-not-cultureinfo-from-ietfl/5937477#5937477

Comment: @Daniel Rose You mean if the user has changed the standards for that language during runtime of the application? Yes then you are right it will not work. As millions of other applications including the ones from Microsoft that read the regional settings once at startup. In any other case it will work just fine.

Comment: No, if they have changed it at all. For example, if the user has the German culture, but changed the decimal separator to '.'. Then this will use for conversion the standard for the language (i.e. ','), but not the actual value (i.e. '.'). I am currently working on fixing our application to handle this BTW.

Comment: @Daniel Rose You are right... I just checked it myself... That is a great disappointment and of course it can happen. Thanks for "awaking" me up with this.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```