# WPF application customize shortdate when using stringformat={}{0:d}

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, datetime-format, uiculture

We are trying to allow the app to have its culture set at runtime and optionally override the way dates are displayed.

We create our own culture with:

```
private CultureInfo CreateCulture()
    {
        // start with basic culture object
        CultureInfo culture = Sys.Workspace.ServerProperties.UICulture ?? new CultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultCulture);

        // override data format
        var dateFmt = Sys.Workspace.ServerProperties.DateFormatOverride;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateFmt))
        {
            culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = dateFmt;
            culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = dateFmt;
            if (dateFmt.Contains("/")) culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
            if (dateFmt.Contains("-")) culture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
        }

        return culture;
    }
```

Then in the initialization of the app we do:

```
        var culture = CreateCulture();

        // set ui culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        // set WPF culture
        LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

We set the "Sys.Workspace.ServerProperties.DateFormatOverride" value to be "dd-MMM-yyyy".  This doesn't seem to be respected by the bindings though.  For example:

```
  <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Text="{Binding NoteDate, StringFormat={}{0:d}}" />
```

The NoteDate is a `DataColumn` with type of `DateTime` but displays the default cultures shortdate pattern.

If I set the main culture to en-GB I will get dd-mm-yyyy, if I set it to en-US I will get mm-dd-yyyy.

When I look at the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and currentUICulture it is set correctly, i.e. it is en-gb and the shortdatepattern and longdatepattern are dd-MMM-yyyy but the dates do not display in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the FrameworkElement's don't look at the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture for globalisation info.

Instead you have to define the culture manually for XAML elements...

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display)

Comment: darn you MS, thats just nasty.  in the end I put a datetimeconverter in for each binding so that at least it was only done at one point.

Comment: But `LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)));` covers that, doesn't it?