# How to create a StaticResource for a class without public constructors

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

WPF bindings uses CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture rather than CultureInfo.CurrentCulture which means they do not respect the preferences specified in Control Panel's *Region and Language* dialog.

To properly implement localisation in a WPF application it is therefore necessary to somehow assign CurrentCulture to the ConverterCulture of every binding.

This is best done with a StaticResource declared in App.xaml but there is a problem: the CultureInfo class has no public constructors. As a result, markup like this

```
<Application x:Class="ScriptedRoutePlayback.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <glob:CultureInfo x:Key="CurrentCulture" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

generates a warning about the fact that CultureInfo has no public constructors. Despite this, the markup is sufficient to register an appropriately typed static resource in the namespace used by the designer, which stops markup references to {StaticResource CurrentCulture} from complaining in the rest of the app.

At run-time the failure of this markup to create an instance of CultureInfo is irrelevant because the accompanying Startup code assigns it from CultureInfo.CurrentCulture:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;

namespace ScriptedRoutePlayback
{
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);
      Resources["CurrentCulture"] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
  }
}
```

### Finally, the question:

What is the preferred way to mark up a StaticResource that refers to an existing object such as a singleton obtained from a static property of a class, especially when said class lacks public constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of defining a StaticResource, have you tried the x:Static markup extension when referring to CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in your bindings?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx

something like:

```
... {Binding ... ConverterCulture={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}
```

alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12115452/1157288) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/993454/1157288) may offer better alternatives for your situation.

Comment: Aha x:Static. I knew there was a way to do this, I've used it before, but for the life of me I couldn't recall how you go about it. Thank you so much for jogging my memory.

Comment: But is it possible to assign this as a resource in the ResourceDictionairy?

i.e. Pseudo-code:
    `<glob:CultureInfo x:Key="CurrentCulture">
        <x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture />
    </glob:CultureInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no point to define resource in XAML.

```
base.OnStartup(e);
Resources.Add("CurrentCulture", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Your code is *exactly* equivalent to mine. The only different is that I have used the indexer and you have called the Add method directly. The purpose of the XAML is to allow other markup to resolve the static resource at design time, as clearly stated in the question.

Comment: if you worry about design time you can use somrthing like this 
    class DesignTimeCultureInfo : System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    {
        public DesignTimeCultureInfo() : base("en-US") { }
    }

Comment: Not a bad idea, although I have now gone a different way with code walking the DOM doing culture fixups on all the bindings because this is more compatible with the Visual Studio designer binding editor.