# Changing the default thousand and decimal separator in a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

Let's say I have a number **1234567.89**. The number is displayed in a WPF TextBlock. I am trying to apply `StringFormat` attribute to the `Text` property so that the number would be displayed like:

```
1.234.567,89
```

As you can see, the thousand and decimal separators are inverted from the invariant culture specification.

I've tried setting numerous combinations for the `StringFormat`, but without success. This is the latest I came up with:

```
Text="{Binding SomeBinding, StringFormat={}{0:#'.'##0','00}}"
```

But the output isn't correct. Also, using `N2` or changing culture isn't an option. I would like to avoid converters if possible.

So, is there a way to change the default separators through XAML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to *change* the culture. Just use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) with specified culture (de-DE should be fine):

```
string output = String.Format(new CultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:N}", yourDoubleValue);
```

Output: `9.164,32`

If you want to do it in XAML, you could try:

```
Text="{Binding SomeBinding, StringFormat={}{0:N}, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"
```

Comment: I think he is trying to do all the stuff in XAML, and I don't see how this can be done without brining some C# in place, at least in the form of custom converter.

Comment: The combination `StringFormat=N2, ConverterCulture=de` would create the desired output without any additional code.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for comment. I cannot test the code, it was my suggestion

Comment: Working! Thanks. :) 

Just edit the post and put `StringFormat={}{0:N}` instead of `StringFormat={}{0:#'.'##0','00}`, not to confuse anybody.

Comment: Note that there are issues with the Binding StringFormat not picking up the current culture automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display