# how binding TextBox.Text to System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName

Tags: c#

there's any way to binding and keep update when the localization change the TextBox.text with Two letter Iso Language name, as this way?

```
xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName}}"/>
```

This gets the error , cannot find the member "TwoLetterISOLanguageName" on target Type

Comment: Check [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display)

Comment: thanks, but CurrentUICulture is not recognized. in xaml code.....