# wpf Datagrid currency is alway $

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, currency

Im making a receipt for a fast food . one column is for price which i try to set it's as currency in xaml 
like this

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="MenuPrice" x:Name="MenuPrice" 
                                        Binding="{Binding MenuPrice, StringFormat=C2}" Width="100" />
```

In other places i get euro sign but only in datagrids i get it as dollar . how can i change it to actually follow the users windows configuration ? like other places.

[image]

if you see at the buttom i have a label which is the result of total like this

```
total.toString("c2");
```

and i get the euro sign but not in datagrid

Comment: Use this: Binding="{Binding Path=PrezzoListino, ConverterCulture='it-IT', StringFormat='\{0:€ #,##0.00\}'}"  in the DataGridTextColumn. Example is for Italian culture, Euro currency and "PrezzoListino" field to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764615/wpf-stringformat-0c-showing-as-dollars).

The [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2764668/1542187) states:

> I'm not sure if this has been fixed in .NET 4, but WPF has never
>   picked up the current culture when rendering things like currency or
>   dates.

It also gives a solution.

Comment: @phi1010 also pointed out a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991526/wpf-xaml-bindings-and-currentculture-display) that was very similar if you wanted to do further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Language property of the DataGrid to your thread's current culture:

```
yourDataGrid.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

I am afraid you cannot do this in pure XAML.